# How to set different attributes for a number of objects Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am attempting to make 10 instances of a class I made, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without setting all of the objects' attributes over and over as it doesn't look great. I want to set different attributes for each instance. Here's an example of what my code is currently doing.

```
from file import MyClass

L = [MyClass() for x in range(10)]

L[0].SetAttribute1('...')
L[0].SetAttribute2('...')
L[0].SetAttribute3('...')
L[0].SetAttribute4('...')
L[0].SetAttribute5('...')
L[0].SetAttribute6('...')

...

L[9].SetAttribute1('...')
L[9].SetAttribute2('...')
L[9].SetAttribute3('...')
L[9].SetAttribute4('...')
L[9].SetAttribute5('...')
L[9].SetAttribute6('...')
```

Comment: Typically, you define `__init__` to set the attributes, then use `L = [MyClass(..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...) for x in range(10)]`. If each object takes different arguments, lists and `zip` come in handy.

Comment: Your example is too abstract to be useful, I'm afraid. There are various ways to easily set attributes on a bunch of objects, but it's unclear which one of those will help you.

Comment: Where do the values for the attributes come from? Is each attribute the same for all instances?

Comment: The example is pretty much what my code is, just with different names. I am using the same 6 setter methods for each instance, but I just want to change the values of the attributes for each of them. @Aran-Fey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyClass` should define an `__init__` method that sets the attributes so that you can define an instance like `MyClass(..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...)`. Then you can define your list not with a list comprehension, but a simpler list literal.

```
L = [
    MyClass(...),
    MyClass(...),
    ...,
    MyClass(...)
]
```

You could write something like the following. It doesn't do much more than separate all the arguments into one place, but you might find it useful.

```
L = [MyClass() for x in range(10)]

# Hard-coding each name, since I doubt there's any real pattern
# to the names
methods = ["SetAttribute1", ..., "SetAttribute6"]

# All the arguments
all_args = [
    (a1, a2, ..., a6),  # for object 1
    (b1, b2, ..., b6),  # for object 2
    ...,
    (j1, j2, ..., j6),  # for object 10
]

for obj, args in zip(L, all_args):
    for m, arg in zip(methods, args):
        getattr(obj, m)(arg)
```

`zip` produces a list like `[(L[0], (a1, a2, ..., a6)), ..., (L[9], (j1, j2, ..., j6))]`. Assuming `obj == L[0]`, `m == "SetAttribute1"`, and `arg=a1`, the line `getattr(obj, m)(arg) == getattr(L[0], "SetAttribute1")(a1) == L[0].SetAttribute(a1)`.

See the Python documentation for more information about `zip` and `getattr`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, however I am doing this for an assignment and the professor wants us to use getter/setter methods to create the attributes. Sorry, I should have specified this in my post.

Comment: Seriously? That's ridiculous.

Comment: @Demons setters and getters are uncommon in python

Comment: It's an intro course so I think they are just trying to get us to become familiar with the idea @chepner

Comment: Then I really wouldn't bother trying to "fix" what you already have; there are better ways of dealing with this type of repetition.

Comment: Okay, I thought as much but I was just hoping there was some easy way to implement a loop of some sort. Thank you for the explanation though, hopefully I will be able to use that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your attributes in a list and set them in a loop.

```
attributes = [['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['qux', 'quux', 'quuz'], ['corge', 'grault', 'garply']]

for i, attr_list in enumerate(attributes):

    L[i].SetAttribute1(attr_list[0])
    L[i].SetAttribute2(attr_list[1])
    L[i].SetAttribute3(attr_list[2])
```

Answer (score -1):

If each attribute is the same for all instances in the list, then use a loop. If they are different, then store the values in a file or database, then use a loop to read the data.

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice All of the attributes are the same, I just want to have different values for each instance

Comment: @Demons Sorry if that wasn't clear. I meant the values of the attributes.